# Trying to get a selenium code to select an option on a drop down menu, not working (Google forms)

Tags: python, selenium

I can't seem to get this to work, I've tried following multiple guides (been trying to get this to work for 2 days now), I am aware of the google TOS and I don't plan on using this system, I just want to try.

The goal is to have it automatically select an option from the Drop Down Menu, however, it constantly errors.

I've tried xpath, jsname's etc, nothing works, here is the error and code.

```
while i < len(name):
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(inputName).send_keys(name[i])
    
    
    time.sleep(1)

    path = '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span'
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(path)
    element.click()

    time.sleep(1)

    option_variable = 'A'
    option_path = "//div[@class='exportSelectPopup quantumWizMenuPaperselectPopup appsMaterialWizMenuPaperselectPopup']//div[@class='quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption appsMaterialWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption']//span[contains(text(), option_variable)]"
    option = driver.find_element_by_xpath(option_path)
    option.click()


    browser.find_element_by_xpath(radioAnswer1).click()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(radioAnswer2).click()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(radioAnswer3).click()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(radioAnswer4).click()
    sleep()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(submit).click()

    i += 1 

    sleep()
```

Comment: The problem could be in the path for the button. Share the link from which you are trying to scrape the data so we can help you better

Comment: share the link please

Comment: Going to send the original form, just remove all the personal info

Comment: before that, try this xpath, button = "//span[text()='Choose']"

Comment: I can't locate the button as google don't use buttons for it, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: If it's not working, tell me at which line you are getting this error

Comment: I can't add the xpath as it doesn't work, it just throws a css error or something like that. There is no clear xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
web = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSflbW3Y2LpAu6DTkJ4KjwDayYaAtvrFT5k8QRe2kJPWrjbbAg/viewform"
driver.get(web)

time.sleep(1)

path = "//div[@class='quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption appsMaterialWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption isSelected isPlaceholder']"
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(path)
element.click()

time.sleep(1)

option_variable = 'A'
option_path = "//div[@class='exportSelectPopup quantumWizMenuPaperselectPopup appsMaterialWizMenuPaperselectPopup']//div[@class='quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption appsMaterialWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption']//span[contains(text(), option_variable)]"
option = driver.find_element_by_xpath(option_path)
option.click()
```

The `path` is the path to the dropdown button itself. `option_path` is path for the option inside the dropdown.

## [EDIT1]

I changed the options path a bit. Also added two `time.sleep` to stop the driver form immediately run the next command. This seems to work better.

## [EDIT2]

Added `option_variable`. This allows us to specify the option we want to click. Also changed the `option_path` accordingly.

## [EDIT3]

Updated the `path`. This is different for the link previously posted.

Comment: I gives me an error and the whole code won't work now

Comment: Just tried your code, I constantly get this kind of error

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='quantumWizMenuPaperselectOptionList']"}

Comment: Are you trying on the link you posted in the comments? This seems to work in my system. I also added a variable to select the necessary option.

Comment: Can you update your question with the new code? Maybe you missed something. This is working fine in my system

Comment: I updated the `path`. This was different for the new link. Try this

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption appsMaterialWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption isSelected isPlaceholder']"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102)

Comment: Wondering if you have discord? This is extending to a discussion and I can't open a chat.

Comment: Can you check the class for the dropdown div in the developer console?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/3d2fa21386c1a0661520654594d7ea60 - image

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102)

Comment: Updating my code now - just updated original post with new code